# Restore min/avg/max graphs in Munin 2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, munin, rrdtool, graph

I just migrated from Munin 1.4 to Munin 2.0.6 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS. The weekly graphs no longer show min/max values, only the avg. How do i get those back?

Thanks
Maciej

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been accepted as a bug by the Munin team. http://munin-monitoring.org/ticket/1293

Answer (score 0):

If you have an old backup maybe exporting all the rrd files to xml and reimporting would work.

Comment: The data was kept, that's no problem. The problem is that it's not rendered the same way. It's been accepted as a bug by the Munin team http://munin-monitoring.org/ticket/1293